How can I measure qutrits in the X basis using cirq?
I attempted to create a custom measurement class which, in my case, allows us to go from the z basis to x basis using a hadamard gate transformation, and then we measure wrt that new basis. However, this custom class is extremely slow compared to cirq.measure, does anyone know any better methods?
class CustomMeasurementGate(cirq.Gate):
  """
  A class representing a measurement gate for qudits in Cirq.

  Attributes:
      dimension (int): The dimension of the qudit (e.g., 3 for qutrits).
      key (str): The key used for storing measurement results.
      basisGate (cirq.Gate, optional): A gate that maps the computational basis
                                        to the desired measurement basis.

  Methods:
      _num_qubits_(): Returns the number of qubits (1 for a single qudit).
      _qid_shape_(): Returns the shape of the qudit (a tuple with the
                     dimension).
      _decompose_(qubits): Decomposes the gate into basis transformation and
                           measurement operations.
      __str__(): Returns a string representation of the measurement gate.
      _measurement_key_name_(): Returns the measurement key name.
  """

  def __init__(self, dimension, key, basisGate=None):
    """
    Initializes a CustomMeasurementGate.

    Args:
        dimension (int): The dimension of the qudit.
        key (str): The key for storing measurement results.
        basisGate (cirq.Gate, optional): A gate to transform the computational
                                         basis to the desired measurement basis.
    """
    self.dimension = dimension
    self.key = key
    self.basisGate = basisGate

  def _num_qubits_(self):
    """
    Returns the number of qubits this gate acts on.

    Returns:
        int: The number of qubits (always 1 for a single qudit).
    """
    return 1

  def _qid_shape_(self):
    """
    Returns the shape of the qudit.

    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple containing the dimension of the qudit.
    """
    return (self.dimension,)

  def _decompose_(self, qubits):
    """
    Decomposes the gate into operations.

    Args:
        qubits (Sequence[cirq.Qid]): The qubits this gate acts on.

    Yields:
        cirq.Operation: The operations that make up this gate.
    """
    ops = []
    if self.basisGate is not None:
      ops.append(self.basisGate.on(*qubits))
    ops.append(cirq.measure(*qubits, key=self.key))
    return ops

  def __str__(self):
    """
    Returns a string representation of the measurement gate.

    Returns:
        str: A string representing the measurement gate.
    """
    return f"M(d={self.dimension}, {self.key})"

  def _measurement_key_name_(self):
    """
    Returns the key name for measurement results.

    Returns:
        str: The key name for measurement results.
    """
    return self.key
```


instead of defining a decomposition you can try to define the action directly by providing the gate's kraus representation by defining the _kraus_ method. if you do also add _has_kraus_ method that returns True

so essentially just describing a singular matrix (in this instance the hadamard gate) but under the _kraus_ method? So how is this faster than decompose?
